# Как изменить расширение navbar bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Нужно что бы кнопка для navbar появлялась не с 992рх, а к примеру с 600рх. Прописала я значит такой `media` запрос:

`@media (max-width: 992px){
    .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-toggler{
        display: none;
    }`.

Прекрасно она исчезла, но и меню тоже пропало остался только сам контейнер пустой. Как вернуть меню изначально как оно было на 1200px? И что самое интересное после 992рх никакие `media` запросы не работают для меню никак. Подскажите как решить ситуацию?

Comment: а вы пользуйтесь `инструментами разработчика` в любом браузере , там 100% видно какой class висит и где

Comment: @ Максим, благодаря этим же инструментам я узнала, что .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-toggler это и есть кнопка

Comment: тогда вы что то не так делаете, надо видеть весь код - предагаю перейти в тем вивер

Answer (score 0):

Сначала просто пропишите для кнопки `display: none;` потом напишите медиа запрос `@media only screen and()` с нужной вам шириной и вставьте для кнопки `display: block;`